# Best practices for doing silverlight authentication and data manipulation on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have an sql azure database. I need an silverlight application with username/password authentication by table from sql azure and makes some operations on data from azure database.

The first that come in my mind is to authenticate by creating a invisible form in aspx page that hosts my silverlight application and send a request from silverlight by calling javascript code and  to validate on server side using asp.net membership provider. Other operations on database also would be done using javascript requests from silverlight.

The other ways that i know is using wcf web services, but i was confused in ways that i should do authentication, how to keep the session in cookie (that when i open this silverlight page in other tab not to authenticate another time authentication). I read also about windows identity foundation but i don't know if it is the best solution. Those approaches with wcf web services i would prefer more because i have no much experience with web development.

**What are best practices to accomplish what i want to do and deploy the application to windows azure with not too much pain?**
Sorry for my bad English, and **thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest have an aspx login page which validate the credentials using membership.Let the silverlight redirect there and logged in. Once it is logged in and if your services are ASP net compatible you can call the services normally.ie it will add the cookies and all.

If you have the Out Of Browser mode you need to get the username and password in your SL app and authenticate using a web service method.

Identity foundation is really good is you are using different identity providers such as google,yahoo,FB,live etc...

Answer (score 1):

For the authentication question - here is a tutorial on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449%28v=vs.91%29.aspx):